# Can i send array with null to GraphQL Nest.js resolver?

Tags: javascript, graphql, nestjs

Can i do that?
I use it in input type:

```
@Field(() => [String], {
    nullable: true,
  })
  date: string[];
```

And when i send on in date key, null on some array index, i got an error. Example:
date: ["2023-02-13 00:00:00", null, null, "2023-02-13 00:00:00"] ->
Error: Expected value of type "String!", found null."

Can i send an array with null in some position?

Comment: What is the GraphQL document you used?

Comment: @ThisaruG Document? What do you mean? I use code-first schema, if you about this

Comment: Document is the request you send to the GraphQL server.

Comment: @ThisaruG `mutation {
    editTableSettings(tableSettings: {
        date: [null , "Mon Oct 17 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0300"],
    }) {
        id
    }
}`